# fix the bug of mouseenter and mouseleave event on mobile

Tags: jquery, mouseenter

I am facing a problem while trying to fix a tiny bug of a website I developed. The homepage has a small icon, which fires an event to show a hidden picture while the mouse moves over it and hide the picture when the mouse leaves the icon. I use Jquery to do that. It works well on the PC browsers, but not on that of any mobile phone. The picture continues to show up even when I moves the "mouse" (my finger) away. Can anybody tell me what I can do to fix that and come with an example? Thank you very much.